# The Question of Proof of Lusin's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

When I read about proof of Lusin's theorem, I got a problem about the case of abritrary f and E (case $mE=\infty$), we can use the conculsion of case of $mE<\infty$, set$E_k=\{x|k\le d(x,0)<k+1\}$, for each $E_k$ we can use case2's conculsion to find closed sets $F_k$, $m((E\cap E_k)\backslash F_k)<\delta/2^{k+1}$, f is continuous on $F_k$, how can I proof $F=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ is a closed set?
THX!!!

Comment: The infinite union need not be closed. You have to use $\bigcup_{n=1}^{N} F_n$ with large enogh $N$.

Comment: But the book proof say that we can proof the $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1} F_n$ is closed set, but I dont know how to proof it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the anwser.
For $\{x_n\}\subset F$, $x_n\rightarrow x$, $x\in E$. Because $\exists\  n \ s.t.x\in E_n$, and $E_n=E \cap B(0,n+1)\backslash B(0,n)$, then $\exists \ N\in N^+\ s.t.\{x_n\}_{n\geq N}\subset F_{n-1}\cup F_n$. And $F_{n-1}\cup F_n$ is closed, so $x\in F_{n-1}\cup F_n\subset F\Rightarrow F$ is closed.